Can an invertible affine transformation turn a conic into a degenerate conic?
I'm trying to prove that no invertible affine transformation sends a conic (i.e., a smooth non singular curve given by a quadratic equation) to a degenerate conic. I know the determinant associated to the conic is nonzero, and the one associated to a degenerate conic is zero. So my plan was to show that invertible affine transformations don't kill this determinant, but I'm stuck and I could not find anything useful on the internet.
Is this even a theorem? If not, a counterexample would be much appreciated.

You will need to assume your affine transformation is invertible.

What is your definition of an affine transformation? Precisely?

My definition is: an affine transformation is an operation on $\mathbf{R}^2$ given by $x \mapsto Ax + u$, for some invertible matrix $A$ and some vector $u \in \mathbf{R}^2$.

So work out the equation of the image of a nondegenerate conic. Edit your post to include the updates.

I noticed you just updated your post to add the assumption the transformation is invertible. Did you make any progress on Ted Shifrin's suggestion to work out the equation of the image of a nondegenerate conic?
